# Determine the source of the change in the richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a form with a richtextbox.
I change the text programmatically and the user is able to change it.
Is there a way to determine what caused the change?

The programmatically changes done by changing its rtf property:

```
rtb1.Rtf = rtb2.Rtf;
```

Comment: Set a flag when you want to change text programmatically, check for this flag in text changed event and you know it.

Comment: @AnasAlweish It can be both

Comment: Either use a flag or check the keyboard and mouse events!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a property `MyRtf` to save your changes

  ```
  public string MyRtf { get; set; }
  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      MyRtf = richTextBox1.Rtf;
  }
  ```
- In `RichTextBox1_TextChanged` event check for `MyRtf`. like this:

  ```
  private void RichTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (richTextBox1.Rtf != MyRtf)
      {
          // do something
      }
  }
  ```